# Find a model by its referenced model (child?) in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find, rails-activerecord

Rails nooby here, looking for some tips.  I've looked around on the site and the Rails website and can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I have an account class

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :access_token, dependent: :destroy
  has_secure_password
```

and of course

```
class AccessToken < ActiveRecord::Base
```

What I want to be able to do in my controllers is `Account.find_by_access_token` or something like that.  Is there a way to do this in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the column's name is `AccessToken` is named `token`, try:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_by_token(token)
    Account.joins(:access_token).where(access_tokens: { token: token } )
  end
end
```

And then use it like this:

```
Account.find_by_token('XXXXXXX')
```